# EditText PasswordtransformationMethod and spans

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-edittext, spannablestring

I am trying to adapt the PasswordTransformationMethod (https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/text/method/PasswordTransformationMethod.java) so that it can work with Editable instance of charsequence which contains spans. What i want is the transformed string also contains the spans present in the source string e.g. styling spans. The reason for doing this is that i need only part of the input to be transformed as a password. e.g input ABCDEF would get transformed as AB...F during text input and retain any styling spans as well.
Looking at the PasswordTransformationMethod above, it looks as though PasswordCharSequence  only implements Charsequence and GetChars thereby losing any spans on the source string.

From the android source code link above, i tried to change the PasswordCharSequence so that it extends SpannableStringBuilder however that gives following exception :

```
08-25 19:41:29.162: E/AndroidRuntime(998): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
08-25 19:41:29.162: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:1734)
08-25 19:41:29.162: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:1711)
08-25 19:41:29.162: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at android.text.TextLine.handleText(TextLine.java:749)
08-25 19:41:29.162: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at android.text.TextLine.handleRun(TextLine.java:1017)
08-25 19:41:29.162: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at android.text.TextLine.measureRun(TextLine.java:416)
08-25 19:41:29.162: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at android.text.TextLine.measure(TextLine.java:295)
08-25 19:41:29.162: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at android.text.Layout.getHorizontal(Layout.java:1145)
08-25 19:41:29.162: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at android.text.Layout.getHorizontal(Layout.java:1123)
08-25 19:41:29.162: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at android.text.Layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(Layout.java:1107)
08-25 19:41:29.162: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at android.widget.TextView.bringPointIntoView(TextView.java:7224)
08-25 19:41:29.162: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at android.widget.TextView.updateAfterEdit(TextView.java:6343)
08-25 19:41:29.162: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at android.widget.TextView.finishBatchEdit(TextView.java:6324)
08-25 19:41:29.162: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at android.widget.TextView.endBatchEdit(TextView.java:6307)
08-25 19:41:29.162: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.endBatchEdit(EditableInputConnection.java:60)
08-25 19:41:29.162: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:436)
08-25 19:41:29.162: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:85)
08-25 19:41:29.162: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-25 19:41:29.162: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
08-25 19:41:29.162: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
08-25 19:41:29.162: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-25 19:41:29.162: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-25 19:41:29.162: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-25 19:41:29.162: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-25 19:41:29.162: E/AndroidRuntime(998):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any hints/pointers appreciated since this is an area where documentation is very sparse.

Answer (score 0):

I manged to fix this myself by getting PasswordCharSequence to also implement Spannable in addition to Charsequnce and GetChars and implemented all spannable methods by delegating those onto mSource e.g. mSource.getSpans(...). The spans are now nicely applied onto the transformed text thus serving my purpose very well!